# A finite ring is a field if its units $\cup\ \{0\}$ comprise a field of characteristic $\ne 2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, finite-rings

Suppose $R$ is a finite ring (commutative ring with $1$) of characteristic $3$ and suppose that for every unit $u \in R\:,\ 1+u\ $ is also a unit or $0$. We need to show that $R$ is a field. Is this true if ${\rm char}(R) > 3$?

Here is what I attempted to do. $\:$  First of all, $\:$ I noticed that the statement is not true if $\ R\ $ is infinite ($ \mathbb F_3[x]$ is an example of an infinite ring which is not a field but it satisfies all the required properties). Now, in a finite ring, a non-zero element is either a unit or a $\:0\:$ divisor, so I tried to show that $R$ has no $\:0\:$ divisors. Clearly, $R$ has no nonzero nilpotent elements (if $x$ is nilpotent, then $1+x$ is a unit, but then $1+(1+x)$ and $1+(2+x)$ is either a unit or $\:0\:.\:$ Hence $x$ is either a unit or $\:0\:,\:$ and since $x$ is nilpotent, it can't be a unit, so we must have $x = 0$). But this does not solve the problem, since $R$ could have elements that are $\:0\:$ divisors but not nilpotent (for example, $\ (1,0)\ $ is a $\:0\:$ divisor in $\ \mathbb Z/3\:\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z/3\:\mathbb Z\ $ but it is not nilpotent).

Another observation I made is that the set of units, together with $\:0\:$ forms a group under addition, so that $J = R^{*}$, together with $\:0\:$ is a subring of $R$. hence we may view $R$ as a $J$-module (and since $J$ is clearly a field, $R$ is a $J$-vector space).

Another thing I tried is to show that $R$ has no proper nontrivial ideals. Viewing $R$ and $J$ as abelian groups, I noticed that a non-trivial ideal of $R$ can contain at most one element from each coset of $J$ in $R$, because if an ideal contains two distinct elements from the same coset of $J$ in $R$, this ideal would have to contain their difference, hence it'd have to contain a unit, hence it would not be a proper ideal. But again, I don't see how this observation leads to a solution.

As for the last part, I suspect that this statement will remain true if ${\rm char}(R) > 3$. Since $1$ is a unit, it follows that $1,2,3,\ldots$ are all either units or $0$, which can only happen if ${\rm char}(R) = p$, a prime number (and then I suspect that $R$ will have to be a finite field), but again  I do not see how to prove (or disprove) this.

By the way, this is not a homework problem. I am studying algebra on my own, and after thinking about it for a few days and making the observations I listed above, I still don't see how to finish the proof. I would appreciate your suggestions. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sorry, after many false starts, I think I have the proof.

Comment: You could fix the title so that it becomes a true statement!

Comment: Dear Mariano, I fixed the title, so now it is a true statement. Thank you!

Comment: See also [this question.](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/912647/242)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The map $f: x\rightarrow {x^3}$ is a homomorphism from $R$ to $R$.  The kernel of $f$ is $\{0\}$ because $x^3=0$ implies $(x-1)^3=-1$, which means that $x-1$ is a unit, hence $x$ is a unit or zero, hence that $x=0$.  So $f$ is 1-1, and, since $R$ is finite, it is thus an automorphism of $R$.

Then there must be an $n>0$ such that $f^n$ is the identity, that is: $x^{3^n}=x$ for all $x\in{R}$

Assume $r$ is not a unit, and let $s=r^{3^n-1}+1$.  A quick computation shows that $s^2=1$, so $s$ must be a unit.  But that means that $s+2$ must be a unit or zero, and $s+2$ is a power of $r$, a non-unit, so $r^{3^n-1}=0$ and $r=r^{3^n} = 0$.

The same argument works for arbitrary prime $p$.  First you prove that $x \rightarrow x^p$ is an ring automorphism, find n such that $r^{p^n}=r$, and then using $s=r^{p^n-1} +1$, prove that $s^{p-1}=1$.  A little harder to prove, requiring to know that

$${{p-1}\choose{i}} \equiv (-1)^i \pmod{p}$$

[That doesn't work when $p=2$, of course, and the theorem is not true for p=2.  In that case, you can take the ring $\{0,1,x,x+1\}$ with the rule $x^2=x$.]

Comment: @Thomas: If you want $\equiv$ rather than $\cong$, the LaTeX code is `\equiv`.

Comment: C'est ingénieux! Ad hoc, where can one learn the inequality mentioned there?

Comment: @awllower - Are you referring to ${{p-1} \choose i} \equiv (-!)^i$?

Comment: Dear Thomas, Thanks a lot for your solution! I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @Thomas: Yes, it truly is.

Comment: @awllower - This fact can be seen either by writing ${{p-1}\choose{i}}=\frac{(p-1)!}{i!(p-1-i)!}$ and doing the arithmetic, or using that ${p \choose i}=0 \pmod p$ when $1\leq i \leq p-1$ and then using ${n \choose k}={{n-1}\choose{k-1}}+{{n-1}\choose{k}}$

Comment: I have used the first method and it is amazing to view the second one. Thanks.

Comment: @awl $\rm {{p-1} \choose i} \equiv (-1)^i\ $ can be proved very simply by comparing coefficients in $\rm\ (1-x)^{p-1}\ =\ (1-x^p)/(1-x)\ =\ 1+x+\:\cdots\:+x^{p-1}\:.$ But this result is not needed - see the elementary proof I posted.

Comment: Thanks, [Bill Dubugue](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/242/bill-dubuque), and I found that seems to be generalisable, doesn't it?

Comment: @awl It's not clear what "that" refers to above.

Comment: [Bill Dubuque](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/242/bill-dubuque): The "that" refers to the identity ${{p-1}\choose{i}} \equiv (-1)^i \pmod{p}$ which seems to be generalisable, doesn't it?

Answer (score 11):

**Hint**  $\:R\:$ is finite so Artinian. $\,R\,$ has trivial Jacobson radical: if $\,j\,$ is in every max ideal then $\, j\!-\!1\,$ is in no max ideal so it's a unit. So, by hypothesis, $\, 1+(j\!-\!1)\ =\ j\,$ is a unit or $0$, thus $0\,$ (else unit $\:j\in$ max ideal). By the structure theorem for Artinian rings (here essentially CRT), $\: R = R/J =$ product of $\:n\:$ fields. $\:n = 1,\:$ else e.g. $\: (1,1) + (-1,1)\, =\, (0,2)\ $ so $\: 1+$ unit $\ne$ unit or $0$.

Note that the proof doesn't invoke $\,{\rm char}\ R = 3\:$ but only $\:2\ne 0\:$ (in the final line), so it works for $\:{\rm char}\ R \ne 2,\:$ as you surmised. But if fails for $\:{\rm char}\ R = 2,\:$ e.g. $ (\mathbb Z/2)^{n}$ for $\:n>1\:$ is not a field but, having $1$ as its only unit, satisfies $\: 1+$ unit $\: =\: $ unit or $0.$

For a simpler way see the method in my [ring-theoretic generalization of Euclid's proof](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?p=1209616#p1209616) to fewunit rings, i.e. an infinite ring has infinitely many maximal ideas if it has fewer units than elements.

If desired, you can specialize this proof to a more elementary proof for your specific case.

See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/32100/is-there-a-third-dimension-of-numbers/32114#32114) on structure theories for nilpotent-free finite dimensional algebras over fields.

Comment: Dear Bill, Thanks a lot for your hints. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 5):

Below is a complete elementary proof of the more general result that you conjectured.

**Theorem** $\ $ Finite ring $ \,R\,\supset\,\mathbb Z/p\ $ is a field, if prime $ \,p > 2\,$  and unit $ \,u\in R\, \Rightarrow\, 1\!+\!u\,$ unit or $\,0$

**Proof** $ \ \ R\,$ satisfies $ \ x^{q} =\, x,\ \ q = p^n,\,$ since, $ $  as Thomas showed, the hypotheses imply $ \ f(x) = x^p\ $ is a permutation on the finite set $ \,R,\,$ so it has finite order $ \, f^{n}\!= 1\,.\,$ For $ \,r \in R\ $ let $ \,e = r^{q-1}.\, $ Then $ \,e^2\!-e\ =\ r^{\,q-2} (r^{q}\!-r)\ =\ 0.\, $ So $ \,(2e\!-\!1)^2\! = 4\,(e^2\!-e)+1 = 1\,$ so $\, 1+(2e\!-\!1)\, =\, 2\,e\,$ unit or $ \,0.\,$ $ \, 2^{-1}\in\mathbb Z/p\, \Rightarrow\, e $ unit or $ \,0.\,\  e$ unit $ \Rightarrow r\,$ unit; $ \ e=0\, \Rightarrow\, r = r^{q}\! = re = 0,\, $ i.e. $ \,r\in R\,$ is a unit or $\,0\,.$

Comment: Ah, yes, that's a nice proof.  Both this proof and my proof first find an idempotent non-unit $e$, but $(2e-1)^2=1$ is a nice simplification, compared to my $(e+1)^{p-1}=1$, and exposes much more clearly why the case $p=2$ is an exception.