# Is possible to define a field in R3?

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-numbers

When we define complex numbers we start creating a field on R2. I think that is impossible to do the same thing on R3 and, in general, on Rn. Do a theorem exist which prove that?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_theorem_(real_division_algebras)

Comment: No. See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/9014/field-structure-for-rn

Comment: see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1784166/why-are-there-no-triernions-3-dimensional-analogue-of-complex-numbers-quate?noredirect=1&lq=1