# Is it possible to have a 3rd number system based on division by zero?

Tags: complex-numbers, number-systems

Is it possible in mathematics to use a third number line based on division by zero; in addition to the real and imaginary number lines?

This is because some solutions blow up when there is a division by zero. Would it be possible to solve them with this new number line?

$\therefore$ on the z axis we would have $\frac{1}{0}$ , $\frac{2}{0}$ , $\frac{3}{0}$ , etc. where,  $p = \frac{1}{0}$ and $p \cdot 0 = 1$ .

[division by zero graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqiBG.jpg)

Is this a viable number system?

A similar question to this one: [Is there a third dimension of numbers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/32100/is-there-a-third-dimension-of-numbers)

Comment: 1=1p*0=1p*(0+0)=1p*0+1p*0=1+1=2

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BRRolKTlF6Q

Comment: Does this mean that $0p = 1$? Is $1p + 1p = 2p$? What does $0$ mean if $x\cdot 0 = 0$ doesn't hold any more?

Comment: This question was asked zillion times already.

Comment: Ever heard of a wheel?

Comment: @Brendan Darrer How will you add fraction? How will you multiply fractions?

Comment: @Jim H - Can you be more specific?

Comment: @BrendanDarrer You are proposing a new number system.  I would like to know how you propose to add and multiply fractions in your new system.

Comment: @BrendanDarrer  I am also curious about your answer to Arthur's question in the comment above.  Are we to abandon the idea that $x\cdot 0 = 0$?

Comment: No, $x \cdot 0 = 0$ is valid in the real and complex numbers. In the division by zero system we are dealing with $p$ i.e. $p \cdot 0 = 1$ .

Comment: In this number system, $\frac{p}{p} = \frac{1}{0} \cdot \frac{0}{1} = 0$ and $p  \cdot p = \frac{1}{0} \cdot \frac{1}{0} =  \frac{1}{0} = p$ . This is work in progress so I may not have all right at the moment. But I think worth asking the question...

Comment: @user328442 I have heard of  a wheel, but this question is not about wheels! How are we to learn anything if we don't ask questions, even one's that appear to be reinventing the wheel to some people. Additionally you haven't given a reference to where this question has been explored before.

Comment: I assume that you are upset and I honestly don't understand why. My intent was to point you in a reasonable direction. Not many people have heard of the wheel as an algebraic structure and the highlighting feature of a wheel is "division by zero". https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_theory

Comment: @user328442 Thanks for clarifying your first comment. I will check that link out!

Comment: @user328442 Thank you very much for the link.  I had never heard of a wheel.

Comment: No problem. It's not exactly common knowledge. I don't know enough myself to give an answer to this question but I figured that a good start would be with a wiki link

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/125186/why-not-to-extend-the-set-of-natural-numbers-to-make-it-closed-under-division-by, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/259584/why-dont-we-define-imaginary-numbers-for-every-impossibility,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to append numbers to the number system, you must explain how they interact with the standard number system.

You need to tell us how to avoid the following:
$$p-p=0$$

$$\frac{1}{0}-\frac{1}{0}=\frac{0}{0}$$

So $$\frac{0}{0} = 0$$

Now $$\frac{2}{3}+\frac{0}{0} = \frac{2}{3} +0 = \frac{2}{3}$$

And, assuming that we still add fractions by finding a common denominator:

$$\frac{2}{3}+\frac{0}{0}=\frac{2\cdot0}{3\cdot0}+\frac{3\cdot0}{3\cdot0}=\frac{0+0}{0} = \frac{0}{0}=0$$

We conclude that 
$$\frac{2}{3} = 0$$

As others have pointed out, there are other things that need to be avoided as well.  You need to explain this new number system more than simply saying I'm going to make division by zero possible.

Added:  You also need to explain associativity (and probably commutativity) in you new system to avoid:

$$2\cdot(0\cdot p) = 2\cdot 1 = 2$$ and $$(2\cdot 0)\cdot p = 0\cdot p = 1$$

So $$2 = 1$$

Answer (score 5):

If you define $p\cdot0:=1$ then you get problems with the distributive property:
$$1=p\cdot 0= p\cdot(0+0) = p\cdot0+p\cdot0=1+1=2$$
Since the distributive property defines multiplication as we know it, you can not drop it without totally changing its meaning and thus not solving the dividing by zero problem.

Comment: If $p \cdot 0 = 1$ then $p \cdot (0 + 0) = p \cdot 0 = 1$

Comment: @BrendanDarrer  Apparently you propose to abolish the distributive property, at least for your new numbers. Or do we keep it for $p \cdot (1+2)$?

Comment: Yes, in this number system $p \cdot (1 + 2) = 3p$

Answer (score 2):

One way to approach this problem could be to imagine zero as a very small number.

So to start with, let us define,

$$small \to 0$$

$$\therefore$$

instead of $$ (2 \cdot 0) \cdot p = 1 $$

as above @Jim H.  Use:

$$2 \cdot small \cdot \frac{1}{small} = 2$$

As

$$(2 \cdot small) \cdot \frac{1}{small} \neq small \cdot \frac{1}{small} = 1$$

$$= 2 \cdot \frac{small}{small} \cdot 1 = 2$$

Do not use $(2 \cdot small) \to 0$ during multiplication and division, otherwise it will produce nonsense such as 2 = 1.

$\underline {The\, p\, number\, system}$

If a very small number, $$s \to 0$$ $$p = \frac{1}{s} \to \infty$$

then, $$\frac{p}{p} = \frac{1}{s} \cdot \frac{s}{1} = 1$$

$$\therefore p \cdot p = \frac{1}{s} \cdot \frac{1}{s} = \frac{1}{s^2} = p^2$$

Also, we could invent a p number,

$$4 + 3p$$

multiply it by s,

$$(4 + 3p) \cdot s = 4 \cdot s + 3 \cdot \frac{1}{s} \cdot s$$

$$4 \cdot s \to 0$$

$$\therefore (4 + 3p) \cdot s = 3$$

$\underline {Adding\, and\, multiplying\, fractions\, in\, p\, number\,system}$

$$p + p = \frac{1}{s} + \frac{1}{s} = \frac{1 + 1}{s} = 2p$$

$$p - p = \frac{1}{s} - \frac{1}{s} = \frac{1 - 1}{s} = \frac{0}{s} = 0$$

$$\frac{2}{3} + \frac{p}{3} = \frac{2 + p}{3}$$

Instead of $$\frac{0}{0} = 0$$ use $$\frac{s}{s} = 1$$

$$\frac{2}{3} + \frac{s}{s} = \frac{2}{3} + 1 = \frac{5}{3}$$

$\underline {Adding\, two\, p\, numbers}$

$$(3 + 2p) + (5 + p) = 8 + 3p$$

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript has its number system close to this with the number [Infinity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Infinity) and the property [NaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN). It just relies on [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) to get these features.

Some examples:

```
1 / 0 = Infinity  
Infinity * 0 = NaN  
Infinity * 432 = Infinity  
1 / -Infinity = -0  
-Infinity / -Infinity = NaN 
Infinity - 1e300 = Infinity  
1e309 = Infinity
564 / -0 = -Infinity  
-Infinity + Infinity = NaN
-Infinity - Infinity = -Infinity
0x33 / 0 = Infinity
Math.log(0) = -Infinity
Math.exp(-Infinity) = 0
```

This is apparently consistent enough to make JavaScript [the worlds most demanded](https://bootcamp.berkeley.edu/blog/most-in-demand-programming-languages/) programming language.

Comment: This is simply projective real line.

Answer (score 1):

[Mathematical wheels](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_theory) support 0/0. Is this sufficient for you?

Comment: Interesting! I will check it out.

Answer (score 1):

In the [zero ring division by zero is possible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_by_zero#Abstract_algebra:%7E:text=In%20the%20zero%20ring%2C%20division%20by%20zero%20is%20possible).

Answer (score 0):

$\textbf {Rules of the p number system using 1/0 and $\infty$ }$

If $p = \frac{1}{0}$ and $p \cdot 0 = 1$. Then I suggest the following rules.

$$p - p = \frac{1}{0} - \frac{1}{0} = \frac{0 \cdot 1 - 0 \cdot 1}{0 \cdot 0} = \frac{0 \cdot (1 - 1)}{0 \cdot 0} = \frac{0}{0} = 1$$

problem lies here (if it is a problem?) $$\frac{0}{0} \neq \frac{0}{\delta x} = 0$$

where $\delta x \to 0$ (see previous answer), going by the rule of $\frac{0}{0} = 1$ .

$\underline{ RULES \, that \,appear\, to \,work}$

$$\frac{2}{3} + \frac{0}{0} = \frac{2 \cdot 0 + 3 \cdot 0}{3 \cdot 0} = \frac{5 \cdot 0}{3 \cdot 0} = \frac{5}{3}$$

$$p \cdot p = \frac{1}{0} \cdot \frac{1}{0} = \frac{1}{0^2} = p^2 = \infty \cdot \infty = \infty^2$$

$$p + p = \frac{1}{0} + \frac{1}{0} = \frac{0 \cdot 1 + 0 \cdot 1}{0 \cdot 0} = \frac{0 \cdot (1 + 1)}{0 \cdot 0} = \frac{2}{0} = 2p$$

$$p \cdot 0 = 1 \neq p \cdot (0 + 0)$$

$$p \cdot (0 + 0) = p \cdot 2 \cdot 0 = \frac{1}{0} \cdot 2 \cdot 0 = 2$$

$$0 + 0 + 0 \,+ ... = 3 \cdot 0 \,+ ...$$

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can divide 1 by 0.

Because,

$$\infty \cdot 0 = 0$$

$$\therefore  \frac{0}{0} = \infty$$

There are infinite 0's in 0 .

$$\therefore \frac{1}{0} = error$$

This is because 0 is not a number. It is a nothing number. There is nothing to divide with! Unless the number actually exits, e.g. a small number such as $\delta x \to 0$.

$$\therefore \sum_{1}^{\infty} 0 = 0 + 0 + 0 \,+... = 0$$

So far in the above discussion we have: $$\frac{0}{0} = 0\,,\, 1 \, \,or \,\, \infty $$

depending on how it's defined.

Comment: In the same way $\sqrt {-1}$ = error, until a complex number was invented $ i = \sqrt {-1}$