# there exist an extension such that this element is a zerodivisor?

Tags: commutative-algebra, ring-theory

Everyone knows that if in a ring A a unit a $\in$ A can´t be a zerodivisor. But could also be possible that "a" not be a zero divisor ( i.e does not exist a nonzero x $\in$ A , such that $ax=0$) but neither a unit ( in A ) **in this case**

My question is so simple in this case, considering the ring of fractions, we know that there exist an extension such that "a" is a unit . My question is, in this case, there exist other extension $J$ of $A$ , such that $a$ is a zero divisor in J ( i.e there exist a nonzero x $\in$ $J$ , such that $ax=0$) . So the question is obviously false if we consider "a" as a unit, but I think that here could be true.

**Remark** : I think that we may assume that A is commutative, but I´m not completely sure ( because we use the ring of fractions the commutative property is needed otherwise the sum in the fraction won´t be commutative). If you note that other properties are also needed please let me know ( like identity , etc).

Comment: What does "in this case" mean? What case? Did you mean to ask: "Suppose $A$ is a ring, and $a$ is a non-unit. Does there exist an extension $B$ of $A$ in which $a$ is a zero divisor?"

Comment: What precisely do you mean by "extension"?  Is $A$ supposed to be a subring of $J$ with the same identity element?  Otherwise you could take $J=A\times A$, and $A\to A\times 0$, in which case every element of $A$ becomes a zero divisor in $J$.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are asking if *a* is not a unit in the (unital, commutative, associative) ring *A*, then is there a ring *B* with *A* ≤ *B* a (unital) subring of *B* such that *a* is a zero divisor in *B*, that is, such that there is some nonzero *b* in *B* with *ab* = 0.

The answer is **yes**, there is always such a ring *B* when *a* is not a unit of *A* (and of course no when *a* is a unit of *A*).

Consider the ring $R=A[x]/(ax)$ and define a homomorphism $f:R\to B$ that is the identity on *A* and takes *x* to *b*.  This is well-defined since *ab* = 0.  In *R* we also have that *ax* = 0, and since $f(x) = b \neq 0$, we must also have $x \neq 0$.  Hence we might as well assume $B=R$ in the first place, but then we'll still need to prove $x \neq 0$ in *R*.

Saying that $x = 0 $ in $R$ is the same as saying $x+(ax) = 0+(ax)$, which simply means $x \in (ax)$, where these ideals are all in $A[x]$. If $x \in (ax)$, then $x = rax$ for some $r \in A[x]$, but obviously by degree arguments, $r \in A$.  Hence $ra=1$ and $a$ is a unit.

The background material is just ideals, [quotient rings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_ring), and [polynomial rings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_ring).  Switching from *B* to *R* is called considering a "universal example".

As far as the non-commutative case goes, most everything already goes wrong and you can no longer invert some non-zero divisor elements.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you are trying to ask:

> Let $A$ be a commutative ring, and let $a\in A$ be an element that is neither a unit, nor a zero divisor. Does there exist a ring $C$ such that $A\subseteq C$ where $a$ is a zero divisor?

You can always construct a "universal" example: let $A$ be a ring, let $B=A[x]$ be the ring of polynomials with coefficients in $A$; then let $I=(ax)$ be the ideal generated by $ax$. Trivially, in $B/I$, we have $ax=0$. So the only question is whether $x\notin I$ and $A\cap I = \{0\}$.

If $x\in I$, then there exists $p(x)\in A[x]$ such that $x = axp(x)$. Writing $p(x) = b_0+b_1x+\cdots + b_nx^n$, we have that $ab_i=0$ if and only if $b_i=0$ (since $a$ is not a zero divisor in $A$), so
$$x = ab_0x + ab_1x^2 + \cdots + ab_nx^{n+1}.$$
This requires $ab_0=1$, which cannot hold because we are assuming $a$ is not a unit. So $x\notin I$, hence the image of $x$ in $B/I$ is not zero.

Similarly, if $r\in A$ and $r\in I$, then $r=axp(x)$ for some $p(x)\in A[x]$. Proceeding as above, we see that we must have $r=0$.

Thus, $A$ embeds into $B/I$, and the images of $a$ and of $x$ are both nonzero, yet their product is equal to $0$. Thus, $C=B/I$ works as an extension of $A$ in which $a$ is a zero divisor.

As for an extension in which $A$ is a unit, let $S = \{a^n\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$. Then $S$ is a multiplicative subset of $A$ and we can consider the localization $S^{-1}A$. This localization contains $A$ because $S$ does not contain any zero divisors, and $a$ is a unit in $S^{-1}A$.

The noncommutative case is a bit more difficult, but the same idea can be used: construct the ring $A[x]$ and the ideal $I=(ax)$. The difficulty lies in the fact that the elements of $I$ are now of the form
$$\sum_{i=1}^n q_i(x)axp_i(x)$$
i.e., polynomials of the form $b_0 + b_1x + \cdots + b_nx^n$, where $b_i\in (a)$, the ideal of $A$ generated by $a$. But this difficulty can be overcome.

*Edited.* You can also try to construct an extension in which $a$ has an inverse by considering $A\langle x\rangle$ (polynomials in a noncentral $x$) and moding out by the ideal generated by $ax-1$ and $xa-1$. But this need not work in general.

The problem of inverting a multiplicative set in a noncommutative ring is non trivial. You can find some results in Lam's **Lectures on Modules and Rings**. For example, given a ring $R$ and a multiplicative set $S$ in $R$ ($SS\subseteq S$, $1\in S$, $0\notin S$), then we say $R'$ is a *right ring of fractions* with respect to $S\subseteq R$ if there is a given ring homomorphism $\varphi\colon R\to R'$ such that $\phi(s)$ is a unit for each $s\in S$, every element of $R'$ has the form $\varphi(a)\varphi(s)^{-1}$ for some $a\in R$ and some $s\in S$, and $\mathrm{ker}\varphi = \{r\in R\mid rs = 0 \text{for some }s\in S\}$.

A multiplicative set $S$ is called *right permutable* or a *right Ore set* if for any $a\in R$ and $s\in S$, $aS\cap sR \neq\emptyset$. We say $S$ is *right reversible* if for any $a\in R$, if there exists $s'\in S$ such that $s'a = 0$, then there exists $s\in S$ such that $as=0$.

We say $S$ is a *right denominator set* if and only if it is both right permutable and right reversible.

> **Theorem.** The ring $R$ has a right ring of fractions with respect to $S$ if and only if $S$ is a right denominator set.

Assume that $a\in R$ is not a zero divisor (on either side), not a unit, and not invertible (on either side). let $S=\{1,a,a^2,a^3,\ldots\}$. This is a multiplicative set. Since we are assuming that $a$ is not a zero divisor on either side, $S$ is right reversible by vacuity. But I believe that it may fail to be right permutable. For example, let $R=A\langle x\rangle$ be the ring of polynomials in a noncommuting variable $x$ with coefficients in a noncommutative ring $A$, and let $a=x$. If $b\in A$ is not central, then $bS\cap xR = \emptyset$, so $S$ is not right permutable.

But if $S$ is right permutable, then you can embed $R$ into a ring in which $a$ is a unit.

Comment: I believe in the last paragraph that A need not embed in A⟨x⟩/I.  Take A to be a 2x2 matrix ring (any connected ring with nontrivial idempotents), a to be E11 (any nontrivial idempotent). Note that (1-E11)*E11 = 0, so E22=(1-E11) is in I, but then E11 = E12*E22*E21 is also in I, so 1 = E11+E22 is in I, and I=A⟨x⟩.

Comment: @Jack: \If anything works, then the above construction will, of course. But you may need some sort of Ore-like condition. Note, though, that if $a$ is a nontrivial idempotent, then $a$ is a zero divisor, since $a(1-a)=0$, and we are supposed to be excluding zero divisors. I'm looking it up in Lam's *Modules and Rings* and will post a correction shortly. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you are asking about a zero-divisor dual of the fraction-field or localization constructions. Regarding such you may find interesting the following paper of Cohn, which is excerpted below for convenience.

Note that rings where every element is a unit or a zero-divisor are sometimes called *quasi-regular*, e.g. finite products of local rings (Artinian), zero-dimensional rings, commutative regular (von Neumann) rings, etc. Searching on said terms should yield a springboard into the literature.

P. M. Cohn. [Rings of Zero-Divisors.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9939-1958-0103202-2)
Proc. AMS  Vol. 9, No. 6, (Dec., 1958), pp. 909-914
[image]

Comment: The AMS journals are available for free on the AMS homepage while they still are behind a paywall on JSTOR. Cohn's paper is available [here](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9939-1958-0103202-2).

Comment: @t.b. Thanks, I've updated it (it was from an old post).

Comment: @OP Beware that the terms "O-ring" and "quasi regular" are rarely used by others, so most readers will likely have no idea what it means.

Comment: At readers: The above comment parrots  [my recent comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4178944/commutative-rings-such-that-all-non-units-are-zero-divisors/4178978#comment8661078_4178978) on @rschwieb's answer. But unlike my comment, the above is false, as a simple search on 'quasi-regular" shows. Further, it is hard to believe that anyone would think that Cohn is proposing O-ring as a name for global use (vs. convenient local abbreviation in his paper).

Comment: @BillDubuque A simple search on quasi-regular showed me a smattering of unrelated uses and a cluster of hits among a small group of authors a few decades ago. It seems to me that this comment is as helpful on this answer as it is on mine!  I just wanted to make sure it's usefulness was maximized.

Comment: Perhaps also telling is that the [linked post on math.overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/42647/rings-in-which-every-non-unit-is-a-zero-divisor), two authors opted to use the term "classical ring" while neither of the terms suggested above appears. It seems the answer to question of which terms are going to be recognized more readily is not as clear as you suggest. Regards.

Comment: @rschwieb quasi-regular is in much wider use than is Lam's terminology. But I wouldn't call it wide use - that's why I qualified it with "*sometimes* used...". You gave no such warning about Lam's term - hence my comment.

Comment: @rschwieb An MO post saying "Lam calls it...." hardly counts as it being in wide use. If you think it is widely used in commutative rings then give some links to support that. Good luck with that.

Comment: @BillDubuque It is just a factual statement: "Lam calls it this." I made no assertion about its popularity.  The reason I mentioned it is because Lam's book is popular and widely read (more read than the particular papers of Cohn's, I think) and that active researchers are using Lam's term.  That seems to be ample justification for mentioning it.

Comment: @BillDubuque If we *apply your same standard to your own case* then I think most people would also agree your terms are not in wide use either. Really, the truth of the matter is that a term is not promulgating because it is not a matter of much interest.  So, my comment applies here as well as yours applies there. I do not even dispute it applies there.  The fact that you dispute it applies here is... telling.  But thanks for participating in this experiment... the last word is yours, if you want it.

Answer (score 0):

What about any integral domain that's not a field? By definition then there exists an element that is non-zero element which is non-invertible, but since the ring is an integral domain this element isn't a zero divisor. For example, consider $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: While the question is unclear, I'm pretty sure it isn't whether there can be a nonzero divisor that is not a unit...