# Commutative rings such that all non-units are zero divisors

Tags: ring-theory, reference-request, commutative-algebra

The construction of the total ring of fractions shows that any commutative ring (with 1) can be put inside a ring whose non-units are zero divisors.

Examples of these rings are the products of fields.

Are there other examples? Do these rings have a standard name?

Comment: Any finite commutative (unital) ring.

Comment: Similarly, any algebra of finite dimension over some field.

Comment: Aha, I forgot they can be non-reduced...

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/573563/29335) but a different question.

Comment: Also [related](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/95248/242)

Comment: Such rings are discussed in [this MO thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/42647/rings-in-which-every-non-unit-is-a-zero-divisor)  (link is from this  [old comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98154/zero-divisors-and-units-for-the-ring-mathbbz-n-mathbbz-with-integer-n/98168#comment231219_98168))

Answer (score 2):

Following Lam's *Lectures on modules and rings* these would be called **commutative classical rings** because they are equal to their localizations at their set of regular elements. (See section 11 in the book.)

That is, all the regular elements are already units: therefore something which isn't a unit has to be nonregular, i.e. a zero divisor.

The broadest, easily described subclass, I think, is that of **strongly $\pi$-regular rings**, which are rings that satisfy the DCC on all chains of the form $xR\supseteq x^2R\supseteq x^3R\supseteq\cdots$ for every $x\in R$.

That includes all one-sided artinian rings and all von Neumann regular rings, covering all examples given in the comments and in the original post.

Suppose, though, that you fabricate strongly $\pi$-regular rings $R_i$ such that there exists $x_i\in R_i$ satisfying $x_i^iR\neq x_i^{i+1}R$.  Then in $R=\prod_{i=1}^\infty R_i$, it is easy to see that nonunits are zero divisors, but $R$ is *not* strongly $\pi$-regular, because the element $x=(x_1, x_2,\ldots)$ spoils things.  So at least we can say rings with your condition are a strictly bigger class than the strongly $\pi$-regular rings.

Comment: @OP Beware that Lam's terminology "commutative classical ring" is rarely used by others, so most readers will likely have no idea what it means.

Comment: To give a helpful version of the preceding comment: in the past, authors in articles have also called these types of (commutative) rings "quasi-regular" or "O-rings".  (The author had these in mind but did not mention it for some odd reason.)