# Find a finite ring with elements other than the zero element, units, or zero-divisors.

Tags: ring-theory, finite-rings

I'm asking this because I could only think of infinite rings where this is true. This must include rings.

Comment: Are you saying you want a ring that does not have any of those elements, or a ring that might have some of them and also has others that do not match those descriptions?  A ring is closed under both of its operations, and while it is not guaranteed to have a multiplicative identity, it must have an additive identity...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a reason why you can't find one! If by "ring" you mean a ring with unity, then every non-zero element of a finite ring $R$ is either a unit or a zero divisor. See [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60969/every-nonzero-element-in-a-finite-ring-is-either-a-unit-or-a-zero-divisor) for a proof.

Comment: Thank you Dan I didn't realize it was already a proof.

Comment: I would be interested in seeing a proof where there isn't a unity element in the ring...

Comment: @ abiessu:  then how do you define a unit or "unitary element"?

Comment: @abiessu Such a ring is necessarily made up entirely of zero divisors, like $2\Bbb Z/8\Bbb Z$. If you can use chat I could sketch the proof there.

Comment: I thought about it and found a partial proof myself...  Thank you for the example :-)