# Property of Modular arithmetic

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic, congruences

If I know that $$g^a \neq 1 \mod b$$ is that always true that if I will take a positive integer $c$ and count $(g^a)^c$, then $$(g^a)^c \neq 1 \mod b$$?

Comment: No. It's *never* true when $g$ is a unit mod $b$, e.g. take $c=\varphi(b)$.

Comment: So if $c = \phi(b)$ it is always true?

Comment: The relation $x^{\varphi(b)}\equiv1$ mod $b$ is true for any unit $x$. In particular if $g$ is a unit then $g^a$ is a unit for any $a\in\Bbb Z$.

Comment: @seaturtles I understand, thank you

Comment: @seaturtles If I can ask you one more question: if I know that $g^{\phi(b)/x} \neq 1 \mod b$, can I also say that always $(g^{\phi(b)/x})^c \neq 1 \mod b$?

Comment: No. It's possible for $\phi(b)/x$ to not be divisible by the order of $g$ while $(\phi(b)/x)\cdot c$ is. I recommend learning modular arithmetic and elementary number theory through a textbook or lecture notes or some other source: you will be able to answer these on your own.

Comment: @seaturtles Ok, I will. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ $ In a finite commutative ring [every element is a unit or a zero-divisor.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/61009/242) By Lagrange's theorem, a unit has finite order (and the converse is clear), $ $ so the units are precisely the elements of finite order, so the elements you seek, those not of finite order, are precisely the zero-divisors.

Answer (score 0):

Iff $\gcd(g^a,b) > 1$. Otherwise, take $c = \phi(b)$.