# Zero divisors and invertible elements

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, self-learning, integers

I have learned about $X_n = \mathbb{Z} / n\mathbb{Z}$. I understand that a zero divisor is an element $x\neq 0$ in $X_n$ such that $xy = 0$ for some $y\neq 0$. I understand that an element $x$ in $X_n$ is invertible if there is a $y$ in $X$ such that $xy=1$.

My question is if it is true that $X_n$ is the disjoint union of the invertible elements and the zero divisors?

I think this is true since for example in $X_5$ there are no zero divisors and all elements are invertible. In $X_6$ the invertible elements are $1, 5$ and the zero divisors are $2,3, 4$. And $X_6$ is exactly the union of those two sets and the two sets are disjoint.

If I am right that this is correct, I would like a hint on how to prove it. (This is not homework, but I would like to try to proof myself if I can get help started.)

Comment: You skipped $0$, and $3$ is also missing from $X_6$.

Comment: @Berci: Ok, so I forgot $0$. I forgot to write $3$. So I guess it is only the nonzero elements that is the union of the two sets. right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* Take $a \in X_n$ and consider the map $x \mapsto ax$. What does its injectivity or surjectivity tell you about whether $a$ is a unit or a zero divisor?

Comment: For a complete solution along this line, see this [spoiler](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/60974/589).

Comment: So just to be 100% clear. I am right in my guess, right?

Comment: Yes. $\,\!\!\,\!$