# Is it possible for an element of a ring to be not a unit and not a zero divisor?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know that in a finite ring, an element must be either a unit or a zero divisor. However, the proof that I have seems to also work for infinite ring.

My proof is as such:
Assume that a $\in$ R is a unit and ab = 0 for some b $\in$ R. Then $b = a^{-1}(ab) = a^{-1}0 = 0$, so a is not a zero divisor. Similarly, if a is a zero divisor, then a is not a unit.

However, if I am not wrong, in $\mathbb{Z}$, all the non-zero elements are both not unit and zero divisor. What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: You seem to have proven that no element can be *both* a unit and a zero divisor, which is a little different from the statement that everything is either a unit or a zero divisor.

Comment: In $Z$, $-1,1$ are units. All other non-zero elements are non-units and none are zero divisors

Comment: In fact $\mathbb Z$ is a counter example of your claim

Comment: You seem to be checking $p \to q$ and then the equivalent $\neg q \to \neg p$.

Comment: I agree with @Platehead. Btw, if it is proved that a unit is not a zero divisors then it is redundant to prove also that a zero divisor is not a unit. The statements are the same.

Answer (score 1):

You have Proved the following statement:

> An element $r\in R$ cannot be both zero-divisor and a unit simultaneously.

But to prove that

> An element must either be a zero divisor or unit in a commutative ring
>   $R$ requires the ring $R$ to be finite.

Please look for the following link:

[Every nonzero element in a finite ring is either a unit or a zero divisor](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60969/every-nonzero-element-in-a-finite-ring-is-either-a-unit-or-a-zero-divisor/60974#60974)