# Proving every nonzero element in a finite ring is either a unit or a zero divisor

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, finite-rings

I've just started learning ring theory, and the book I'm using uses "Every nonzero element in a finite ring is either a unit or a zero divisor" implicitly without explanation. So I came across this proof here on this site:

> In a finite commutative ring with unity, every element is either a unit or a zero-divisor. Indeed, let $a\in R$ and consider the map on $R$ given by $x \mapsto ax$. If this map is injective then it has to be surjective, because $R$ is finite. **Hence, $1=ax$ for some $x\in R$ and $a$ is a unit.** If the map is not injective then there are $u,v\in R$, with $u\ne v$, such that $au=av$. But then $a(u-v)=0$ and $u-v\ne0$ and so $a$ is a zero divisor.

**I understand all of the proof, except the part: Hence, $1=ax$ for some $x\in R$ and $a$ is a unit.** How is this conclusion reached? Thanks for your time!

Comment: Note that the bolded hypothesis is only valid when the map is injective.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Every nonzero element in a finite ring is either a unit or a zero divisor](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60969/every-nonzero-element-in-a-finite-ring-is-either-a-unit-or-a-zero-divisor)

Answer (score 3):

If $x\mapsto ax$ is surjective, in particular its image contains $1$.  This means exactly that there is some $x$ such that $ax=1$.

Comment: Why does $x\mapsto ax$ is surjective imply that its image contains 1?

Comment: @TonyTarng: by hypothesis, your ring $R$ has unity. Hence, if the map $x \mapsto ax$ from $R$ to $R$ is surjective, then every element of $R$ has a preimage under this map; this includes $1 \in R$.

Comment: @AlexWertheim I got it. Thanks a lot!