# if $a\neq 0$ is not a divisor of zero then some positive power of a is equal to 1

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let A be a finite commutative ring with unity. Prove that if $a\neq 0$ is not a divisor of zero then some positive power of a is equal to 1.

So A is finite so A=$\{a,a^2,a^3,...a^n\}$ and one of these $a^i=1$. I'm not sure where to take this proof if someone could help me out.

Comment: The set of positive powers of $a$ is not necessarily the whole of the ring $A$.

Comment: From the reference of your [last question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60969/every-nonzero-element-in-a-finite-ring-is-either-a-unit-or-a-zero-divisor) $a$ is a unit. Now consider the group of units of $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the set $X = \{ a, a^2, a^3, \dots \} \subset A$, being $A$ finite there must be two distinct indices $i,j \geq 1$ such that $a^i = a^j$ , which implies $a^i - a^j = 0$. Now suppose $i > j$, then: $a^j ( a^{i-j} - 1) = 0$. We suppose that $a$ is not a divisor of zero so $a^j$ is not a divisor of zero and it is not zero, therefore $a^{i-j} - 1 = 0$, equivalently: $a^{i-j} = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

You have no reason to believe that $A=\{a^i\mid i=1,2,\ldots\}$, but you do know the right hand side is a subset of $A$, and hence finite.

So the elements of the set of powers *cannot be all distinct* (it would be absurd if infinitely many distinct elements existed inside a finite set.)

So there exists $a^n=a^m$ for some $m < n$. Now look at $a^m(a^{n-m}-1)=0$ and ask yourself how the property that $a$ isn't a zero divisor will help you.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

The set of positive powers of $a$ is finite, so there exist positive integers $r, s$, $\;r<s$, such that $a^r=a^s$.