# How to find all invertible elements in $F_3/(f(x))$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Is there a algorithm or smt like this? For example, $F_3/f(x) = \{ax^3 + b x^2+c x+d | a,b,c,d \in F_3\}$ where $f(x)=x^4+2x^2+x+2$ and $F_3=Z/3Z$. Am I right that there are 8 zero-divisors

Comment: Do you mean $F_3[x]/(f(x))$? Also $f(x)$ must be given as "a" polynomial, not  a set of polynomials.

Comment: oh, yes, of course, it was a misprint, sorry

Comment: you should edit the question correctly before someone can help.

Comment: $F_3/f(x) = \{ax^3 + b x^2+c x+d | a,b,c,d \in F_3\}$

Comment: Does $F_3$ mean $\Bbb Z/3?$  Does unit mean invertible?

Comment: Yes, $F_3$  mean $\ℤ/3$, and yes, unit means invertible

Comment: @J_G Clarifying the comments is good, but after that you really should also correct the question content too. Apparently you know how... I see you self-edited the question already at least once.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

In a finite commutative ring every non-zero element is either a zero-divisor or a unit. So instead of finding a unit we can aim at finding the zero divisors (which might be easier).

Let $R=\mathbb{F}_3[x]/\langle f(x) \rangle$. First observe that in $\mathbb{F}_3$ we have
$$f(x)=x^4+2x^2+x+2=(x+2)^2(x^2+2x+2)$$
Say $g(x)$ is a zero divisor. Then $\exists \, \text{ nonzero } h(x)$ such that $g(x)h(x) \equiv 0 \pmod{f(x)}$. This also means we want
\begin{align*}
g(x)h(x) &\equiv 0 \pmod{(x+2)^2}\\
g(x)h(x) &\equiv 0 \pmod{x^2+2x+2}
\end{align*}
So we need to find zero divisors in $\mathbb{F}_3[x]/\langle x^2+2x+2 \rangle$ and also in $\mathbb{F}_3[x]/\langle (x+2)^2 \rangle$.

Since $x^2+2x+2$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_3[x]$, so this ring is a field. Hence all non-zero elements are units in this ring. So no zero divisors.

But for $\mathbb{F}_3[x]/\langle (x+2)^2 \rangle$, $x+2$ is an obvious zero divisor. Check if there are others!!

Hopefully now you can complete it.

Comment: I understand, but "In a finite commutative ring every non-zero element is either a zero-divisor or a unit.". Is it a theorem? How to prove it?

Comment: @J_G check this out https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60969/every-nonzero-element-in-a-finite-ring-is-either-a-unit-or-a-zero-divisor

Comment: There are 8 zero-divisors, am I right?