# How many zero divisors does a ring have?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modular-arithmetic

How can I calculate the number of zero divisors in the ring $$\mathbb Z /n\mathbb Z$$ for $n = 1.000.000$?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Are you familiar with Euler's totient function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

[Every nonzero element in a finite ring with unity is either a unit or a zero divisor.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60969/every-nonzero-element-in-a-finite-ring-is-either-a-unit-or-a-zero-divisor)

Can you calculate the number of units in the ring $\mathbb Z/1000000\mathbb Z$?