# Every ideal of a finite principal ring is generated by a zero divisor

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, finite-rings

I stumbled upon this while doing introductory exercises to abstract algebra, but since i am still rather inexperienced in the subject, i would appreciate a second opinion. We will assume the ring to be commutative for simplicity, but I am somewhat certain that a noncommutative version using left and right ideals exists. I do not know if the assumption that $R$ is principal is necessary.

We start by stating that in a finite principal ring $R$, every element is either a unit or a zero divisor ([Proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/60974/1090050)). Furthermore, every ideal $I$ generated by a unit $a$ is equal to $R$: $$\forall c \in R: c = 1\cdot c = aa^{-1}c = a(a^{-1}c) \in I$$
Now this immediately implies that *every* ideal $\neq R$ must be generated by a zero divisor, assuming it exists. Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: Yes, it's right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are absolutely correct.