# Are these two equalities equivalent: $ABA=0$ and $BA=0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, examples-counterexamples, matrix-equations

There are two equalities as follows:

> $ABA=0$ , $BA=0$
>
> where $A$ and $B$ are two $n\times n$ matrices.

Are the mentioned equalities the same? if not, why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is **0**?  The $n \times n$ zero matrix?

Comment: yes. By **0** I mean an n-by-n zero matrix

Comment: Somewhat related: [In a ring $aba=0$ implies $ab=0$ or $ba=0$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/200674)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The equality $BA=0$ obviously implies $ABA=0$. But the reverse implication does not hold. For instance let 
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix},\ \ B=\begin{bmatrix} 0&0\\1&0\end{bmatrix} . 
$$
Then $ABA=0$, but $BA\ne0$.

By changing $B$ to $$ B=\begin{bmatrix} 0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix} ,$$one gets an example where $AB\ne0$, $BA\ne0$, and $ABA=0$.

**Edit:** as mentioned by the user Improve, it is worth noting that the double implication does hold when $A$ is invertible.

Comment: Are both $BA=0$  and $AB=0$ equivalent to $ABA=0$ ? I mean can we separate $ABA=0$ to both $BA=0$  and $AB=0$?  @Martin Argerami

Comment: No. Just a brief change in the example accounts for that. I have edited it into the answer.

Comment: Might want to mention that the equivalence is true when $A$ is invertible.

Comment: Good point. $ $

Comment: Why is the equivalence held when A is invertible? @Improve

Comment: Because you can multiply the inverse on both side :-)

Comment: In particular, you will deduce B is 0 matrix.

Answer (score 13):

Consider $A = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, B = I$. Then $BA = AB = A \neq 0$ but $ABA = A^2 = 0$

Answer (score 8):

Not equivalent. Let $n = 2$. Take $A$ as the matrix that kills the unit vector $e_1$, say, and $B$ as the rotation of $90^\text{o}$. 
Then $A B A$ kills all vectors.
But $B A$ only kills those along $e_1$.

Answer (score 4):

If these two equations would be the same then also for $B=A$ the equations $A^3=0$ and $A^2=0$ should be equivalent what certainly is not the case for all matrices,

consider for example  the case of matrix

$A= \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0  \end{bmatrix}$,
$A^2= \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0  \end{bmatrix}$,
$A^3= \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0  \end{bmatrix}$.