# Characterize all finite unital rings with only zero divisors

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, finite-rings

Is it true that for every finite (for simplicity, commutative) ring $R$ in which every element not equal to $1$ is a zero divisor, is isomorphic to the zero ring or $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ etc. The characterizing property of this sequence of rings is every element is a root of $x^2 - x$.

**My work**: First, consider the characteristic of $R$. If $R$ has characteristic not $1$ or $2$ then $1 \not= -1$ and $-1$ would then be a unit, not a zero divisor. If $R$ has characteristic $1$ then it's the zero ring. So take $R$ to have characteristic $2$. $R$ is a finite-dimensional algebra over $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$; this implies its cardinality is $2^n$ for some $n$.

Then induction over $n$. Base case: $n=1$ so the cardinality of $R$ is $2^1$ which means $R \cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. Inductive case: Assume it's true for all such rings with cardinality less than $2^n$; now we'll show it's true for $R$ with cardinality $2^n$. Take any element $x$ and forms its ideal $xR$. We see that $R/xR$ is a ring in the same form and so we apply the induction hypothesis to conclude that for any $y \in R$, $y^2 - y \in xR$. At this point I'm thinking of showing that $(1+x)R \cap xR = \{0\}$.

Comment: Is $R$ assumed to be commutative?

Comment: @MooS Maybe. Does it make a difference? For simplicity, yes.

Comment: The commutative case seems a little bit easier to me. Honestly I do not really know if there is a counterexample in the non-commutative case.

Comment: I won't be so sure that $R/xR$ has the same property.

Comment: @user26857 If $x$ is nonzero then $R/(x)$ has strictly smaller cardinality, which the induction hypothesis covers. Although it still remains to be seen if we can induct. Also I don't think we've proven it's commutative, and so $R/xR$ isn't automatically a ring (maybe that's what you're getting at).

Comment: @anon The induction hypothesis applies to the rings with the same property, that is, all non-zero elements are zero-divisors. Now suppose $a \bmod (x)$ is non-zero (in $R/(x)$). In particular $a\ne 0$, so there is $b\in R$, $b\ne 0$ such that $ab=0$. Now what if $b\in (x)$? How can we conclude that $a\bmod (x)$ is also a zero-divisor?

Comment: @user26857 Ah yes, that is a good point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commutative case is very easy:

$R$ is reduced, since $1+a$ is a unit, if $a$ is nilpotent. Hence the product of all maximal ideals is zero. The Chinese Remainder Theorem then implies
$$R = R/\mathfrak m_1 \times \dotsc \times R/\mathfrak m_s,$$

so $R$ is a product of fields.

We consider the unit groups and deduce

$$\{1\} = R^* = (R/\mathfrak m_1)^* \times \dotsc \times (R/\mathfrak m_s)^*,$$

which shows that each field occuring is $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$.

Comment: I get that there are no nilpotents apart from $0$. I don't know what you mean by reduced and maximal ideal. Sorry. Maybe I asked a question beyond my level, or I didn't clearly state my level of knowledge.

Comment: I'll think about your answer for a bit.

Comment: Definitions for [maximal ideal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_ideal) and [reduced ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_ring).

Comment: @user3491648 Also proved along the way in [this answer.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/30566/242)