# When do units plus 0 form a subring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

For which (commutative, unital) rings $R$ is it the case that $R^*\cup \{0\}$ is a subring of $R$?
Here are the only examples I could think of:

- a field
- $R[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ for $R$ with the above property
- $(\mathbb F_2)^\alpha$ for any $\alpha$; here the only unit is $1=(1,1,\ldots)$. This doesn't work for any other field, because if $a\in k^*$, $a\neq 1$, then $(a,1,1,\ldots)-(1,1,1,\ldots)$ is not a unit.
- Any other ring with characteristic 2 and no units besides 1 (is there any way to categorize these?)

Are there any others?

Comment: Related: [A finite ring is a field if its units $\cup\ \{0\}$ comprise a field of characteristic $\ne 2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/30556/242) (and its links).

Answer (score 1):

In your notation $k=R^*\cup\{0\}$ is a subfield of the ring $R$. So, you are asking for $k$-algebras $R$ with the property that  $R^*=k^*$. There are many rings with this property.

For any smooth projective absolutely irreducible algebraic curve $C$ over $k$
and any point $P$ of $C$, consider the subring $R$ of the function field $C(k)$
that consists of functions without poles outside $P$.
The ring $R$ has the property that $R^*=k^*$.